# Rails - Rendering a page in JSON based conditionally on the URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have a page I want to conditionally render in json based on if there is either .json or /.json at the end of that URL, like how reddit does it, for example https://www.reddit.com/r/pics/.json renders the page in json. Rendering the page in json is easy enough with the `render json: @some_data`, however I'm not really sure how to make this conditionally based on the url. How do I go about setting this up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all define your routes as [resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default)

```
resources :xvaziris
```

Just append the url with `.json`

Here is an example:

```
http://localhost:3000/xvaziris.json
```

[image: json example]

Comment: Hmm. Doesn't seem to be working. I've defined my route like so: `resources :reviews` and put in my url like so: `url-to-website/reviews/22.json` and it gives me an error.

Comment: nvm, something was wrong in my respond_to block it works.